# Next.js Dynamic Page

Tags: next.js

I want to drill down on a user from a page with all users. When I go to the detail page, I need to make an 'id' based query. Why can't I access the 'id' I sent without getting all users with 'getStaticPaths'? I just want to get the id sent with the route and send a request. Example: '/user/6'. Why do I have to pull all the data again with getStaticPaths? Why am I fetching all the data again when I can solve the problem with a single id based query?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve but `getStaticPaths` only gets called once during build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) to define the dynamic paths that should generate a `HTML` file during the Next.js [static HTML export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) build process from development to production.

Since your pages use props you would need to set the props in [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) so they can be accessed when the page is building.

#### Development

`getStaticPaths` does not get called.  `getStaticProps` will run on every page load.

#### Build

`getStaticProps` will run once per route and `getStiatcPaths` will run once per build.

#### Production

Neither `getStaicPaths` nor `getStaitcProps` get called in production

---

#### Alternative static approach

In your case, it will generate a `HTML` file for every user. This might not be ideal and you could alternatively run the query on the page to defer building any user `HTML` files.

example get user query hook

```js
  const useGetUserQuery = (id) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      const getUser = async () => {
        try {
          setLoading(true);
          const data = await userQuery(id); // your query logic
          if (data) {
            setUser(data);
          } else {
            setError(true);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          setError(true);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };
      if(!id) {
       setError(true);
      } else {
       getUser();
      }
    }, [id]);

    return { error, loading, user };
  };
```

example usage

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const UserPage = () => {
 const { query } = useRouter();
 const userId = query.id; // your dynamic route name user/[id].js
 const { error, loading, user } = useGetUserQuery(userId);
 
 if(error) return <>404 user not found</>;
 if(!user|| loading) return <>loading...</>;
 console.log(user);
 return <>User found</>;
}
```

Lastly, you can also use [getServerSide](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) props to do server side rendering.